# How to Create An Application with Administrator Authentication Parameteres are defined inside the application?

Tags: delphi, authentication, winapi

Trying to create an application which will run in my domain with admin power for this application. And this application don't need to ask for Administrator permission as those parameters are to be Included while developing the application.

Using Delphi And Firebird for Development purpose.

Comment: Either a service or a scheduled task.

Comment: I think this question needs a lot of improvement to make clear what is actually being asked.

Answer (score 0):

Let your application be a non-privileged application and then detect if you are running with administrative privileges, and if not, create an administrator token with the login credentials you require (API call LogonUser) and execute yourself again using this token (API call CreateProcessAsUser).

Comment: I'm guessing, although the question far from clear, that the asker wants to avoid UAC dialogs

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I guessed as much, and I have been successful in obtaining an elevated token for a user via LogonUser and GetTokenInformation (confirmed that it is elevated via another call to GetTokenInformation), but when I try to call CreateProcessAsUser, I get error _0x00000542, Either a required impersonation level was not provided, or the provided impersonation level is invalid_. Any tips?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan And if that's not an option?

Comment: Don't know. Perhaps that's all there is.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Well, Scheduled Task and Run as Administrator does it, so it is - technically - possible. The only question is how (and if the support is available using a standard API call).

Comment: are you using the normal or the linked token (the elevated one)? see https://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2011/08/11/gettokeninformation-with-tokenlinkedtoken-returns-error-1312/

Comment: There isn't going to be an API to call to avoid UAC or indeed any security mechanism. If there was, the system would be insecure. With services and scheduled tasks, credentials still need to be provided but they don't need to be provided repeatedly.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan How "insecure" ? I have provided user credentials via the LogonUser so it is not something any program can just use to gain administrative rights. You still have to provide the credentials (name + pwd). I do not want to avoid UAC - just be able to provide the security information programmatically instead of by prompting user.

Comment: @Remko I have tried multiple tokens and methods, so I am not sure exactly which ones in which combination. I am sure, however, that I have tried a (verified via GetTokenInformation) elevated token in the CreateProcessAsUser call.